# SIGPROF kills my server when using google perftools

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals, google-perftools

I have a multithreaded server process, written in C/C++ that I am trying to profile with Google perftools.  However when I run the process with perftools, pretty soon my server stops with a "syscall interrupted" error, that I think is being caused by the incoming SIGPROF.  (The actual system call that is being interrupted is deep inside my call to [zmq_recv](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-recv), but I don't think it's really important which one it is.)

Is this expected behavior?  Should I be explicitly handling this case somehow?  Or is something going wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the zeroMQ documentation for **[zmq_recv()](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-recv)** we can expect it to return **`EINTR`** if a signal is received when it is in progress.

Generating signals right in the middle of the **`zmq_recv()`** call would be a tough task for any test. Luckily **gperftools** generating a ton of `SIGPROF`s has uncovered this subtle "bug" in your code.

This **must** be gracefully handled in **your** code as the zeroMQ framework is gracefully ceding control. The retry logic could be as simple as modifying the existing call :

```
    /* Block until a message is available to be received from socket */
    rc = zmq_recv (socket, &part, 0);
```

with the new one(with retry logic) as follows :

```
   /* Block until a message is available to be received from socket
    * Keep retrying if interrupted by any signal
    */
    do {
        rc = zmq_recv (socket, &part, 0);
    } while(errno == EINTR);
```

Also [**install a signal handler function**](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/signal/install.html) in your program. One can simply ignore the interruption due to `SIGPROF` and keep retrying.

Finally, you may want to handle specific signals and act accordingly. For example, gracefully terminating your program even if user presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while your program is waiting on **`zmq_recv()`**.

```
   /* Block until a message is available to be received from socket
    * If interrupted by any signal,
    * - in handler-code: Check for signal number and update status accordingly.
    * - in regular-code: Check for status and retry/exit as appropriate
    */

    do {
        rc = zmq_recv (socket, &part, 0);
    } while(errno == EINTR && status == RETRY);
```

In the interest of keeping code "clean", you will be better served by using the above snippet to write your own `static inline` function wrapper around **`zmq_recv()`** which you can call in your program.

Regarding the decision to make **`zmq_recv()`** return `EINTR` upon receiving signals, you might want to checkout this article that talks about the [**worse is better philosophy**](http://www.jwz.org/doc/worse-is-better.html) behind such a design that is simpler from an implementation point-of-view.

---

**UPDATE**: Documented code to handle signals in the context of **`zmq_recv()`** is available at **[git.lucina.net/zeromq-examples.git/tree/zmq-camera.c](http://git.lucina.net/zeromq-examples.git/tree/zmq-camera.c)**. It is along the same lines as explained above, but it looks well tested and ready to use with detailed comments graciously sprinkled all over (yayyy zeromq!).

Comment: The condition should be while(errno == EINTR) instead of while(rc != EINTR)

Comment: Agreed. Updated the code snippets. Thanks for the code-review! :-)